# Concatenate value to variable name

Tags: java, variables

I need to get the value of different text boxes.

I want to get the value of each one using a `for` loop or something like this:

```
txt0,txt1,txt2,txt3;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  String valor = (txt+i).getText();
}
```

There is a way to get the value by concatenating another value to the name of the textbox or any other object??

Comment: You *might* be able to get something to work that way using reflection, but it would be way, way easier to just add the text boxes to a Collection (or an array) and then iterate over each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you have access to the variables but you can use an array instead. This will make looping much easier.

```
TextBox[] text = {txt0, txt1, txt2, txt3};

for (TextBox txt : text) {
   String valor = txt.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if I have well understood your question so this might be a wild guess*.

If you want to have all your text boxes fields concatenated value, You need to have a set that can hold all of their references and your main solution should be JAVA Collections API.

You need to store all of your `JTextField` objects references in a `Collection` (each time you construct a new one add it to the `Collection`), can be a `List`, `Map` or a `Set`, then iterate over that `Collection` once it is filled and build your concatenated `String` using their values (I would suggest to use a `StringBuilder` that the way you actually do it):

```java
// Initialize your Collection, will be an ArrayList for this e.g.
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>;

// Instantiation example, it should be done for all fields
JTextField txt0 = new JTextField(20);
textFields.add(txt0);
// Do the same for txt1, txt2 ...

// Iterate over your List to get the concatenated String
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(JTextField textField : textFields){
  sBuilder.append(textField.getText());
}

// Print your final value
System.out.print(sBuilder.toString());
```